# How to fix CSP script-src-elem Error although it is being defined?

Tags: node.js, pug, content-security-policy, ocsp

I have something like this in a meta tag in my pug. I have a ton 2 3  CDN in my File.

```
 meta(http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy' content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src-elem * 'unsafe-inline';"  )
```

I get an error something like this although I have defined the script-src-elem.

`Refused to load the script '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`
I would really appreciate your help. Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me guess. You use PUG linked with Express. In the Express you use Helmet security middleware.

The point is that Helmet 4 publishes CSPs by default via an HTTP header, and
`script-src 'self'` is a fragment of this Helmet's default CSP.

Since you have one CSP published, you can't relax it using a meta tag. In case of 2 CSPS published all sources should pass unscratched through both CSPs. Therefore your `script-src-elem * 'unsafe-inline'` from meta tag does not trigger violation, but `script src 'self'` from the CSP HTTP header - does rise it.
You have to remove meta tag and configute Helmet via [helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(options)](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet#user-content-reference). Or [disable](https://helmetjs.github.io/) CSP in Helmet and use a meta tag:

```
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: false,
  })
);
```

Comment: Exactly that was the issue. Thank you so much for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your browser does no support this directive.

The Message you get is explained on MDN [script-src-elem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src-elem)

> If script-src-elem is absent, User Agent falls back to the script-src
> directive, and if that is absent as well, to default-src.

And by the way:

> specifies valid sources for JavaScript  elements, but not inline script event handlers like onclick